# Indeterminate state in Checkbox/ToggleButton changes to Unchecked on mouse over

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I have a threestate RadioButton (same issue with ToggleButton) with a custom template in WPF (using Blend 4.0) and I turn it to 'Indeterminate' state on Load. This works fine, and I want to keep it in that state till the user clicks it. The problem is it changes to Unchecked state as soon as the user puts the mouse over it.

How can I prevent this unwanted change of state from happening? Is this the default behavior or something I might have changed accidentally?

I also would like that after clicked it would chang directly to the 'Checked' state but that's a different question and I've read it might have to do with changing the order of states.

Comment: Sounds like you may have your States mixed up in your template (provided you're using a VisualStateManager instead of Triggers), might want to share your code on this one.

Comment: Definitely going to need to see some code...

Comment: I think I might have had my States mixed up. I re wrote my code and it works as expected now.